# Cant resolve "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" using jest in @nrwl monorepo angular 11

Tags: angular, jestjs, babel-jest, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am porting an app from an old-style angular repo to @nrwl/nx.  I have one app and one lib that gives me issues:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { Hash } from './lib/hash';
```

I am not using hashjs-es directly, it is a dependency of another library.

I have read PAGES on this issue, but nothing seems to work.  I am not sure I have the transformIgnorePattern setup right, and I am not a babel pro.

**Suggestions for finding the issue?**

**jest.config.js** (in my apps/)

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'nfconsole',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/nfconsole',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "../../node_modules/(?!hashjs-es).+\\.js$"
  ]
};
```

**.babelrc** (in apps/)

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env"]
}
```

**tsconfig.spec.ts** (in apps/)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test-setup.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

**test-setup.js** (in apps/src)

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

package.json includes

```
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
```

the relevant section of **angular.json**

```
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/<myapp>/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/<myapp>/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "passWithNoTests": true,
            "setupFile": "apps/<myapp>/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing a similar issue with a local (not 3rd party) lib that goves me "unexpected token ... export .. " errors.